# What does `training=True` mean when calling a TensorFlow Keras model?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

In TensorFlow's offcial documentations, they always pass `training=True` when calling a Keras model in a training loop, for example, `logits = mnist_model(images, training=True)`.

I tried `help(tf.keras.Model.call)` and it shows that

```
Help on function call in module tensorflow.python.keras.engine.network:

call(self, inputs, training=None, mask=None)
    Calls the model on new inputs.

    In this case `call` just reapplies
    all ops in the graph to the new inputs
    (e.g. build a new computational graph from the provided inputs).

    Arguments:
        inputs: A tensor or list of tensors.
        training: Boolean or boolean scalar tensor, indicating whether to run
          the `Network` in training mode or inference mode.
        mask: A mask or list of masks. A mask can be
            either a tensor or None (no mask).

    Returns:
        A tensor if there is a single output, or
        a list of tensors if there are more than one outputs.
```

It says that `training` is a Boolean or boolean scalar tensor, indicating whether to run the `Network` in *training mode* or *inference mode*. But I didn't find any information about this two modes.

In a nutshell, I don't know **what is the influence of this argument**. And what if I missed this argument when training?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Some neural network layers behave differently during training and inference, for example Dropout and BatchNormalization layers. For example

- During training, dropout will randomly drop out units and correspondingly scale up activations of the remaining units.
- During inference, it does nothing (since you usually don't want the randomness of dropping out units here).

The `training` argument lets the layer know which of the two "paths" it should take. If you set this incorrectly, your network might not behave as expected.

Comment: @Dr.PP I think people refer to training mode when calling `fit()` and refer to inference mode when calling `evaluate()` and `predict()`.

Answer (score 4):

Training indicating whether the layer should behave in training mode or in inference mode.

- training=True: The layer will normalize its inputs using the mean and variance of the current batch of inputs.
- training=False: The layer will normalize its inputs using the mean and variance of its moving statistics, learned during training.

Usually in inference mode **training=False**, but in some `networks` such as `pix2pix_cGAN‍‍‍‍‍‍` At both times of inference and training, **training=True**.