# tensorflow serving returning NaN when predict

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I had trained one GAN model and saved the generator by the following function:

```
    tf.keras.models.save_model(
        generator,
        filepath=os.path.join(MODEL_PATH, 'model_saver'),
        overwrite=True,
        include_optimizer=False,
        save_format=None,
        options=None
    )
```

It predicts successfully when  load model by tf.keras.models.load_model in python. But when serving the model in tensorflow model server,  the model returns NaN value.
I serve the model by the following:

```
zhaocc:~/products/tensorflow_server$ sudo docker run -t --rm -p 8502:8501     -v "/tmp/pix2pix/sketch_photo/model_saver:/models/photo2sketch"     -e MODEL_NAME=photo2sketch     tensorflow/serving &
[3] 30089
zhaocc:~/products/tensorflow_server$ 2020-06-17 12:57:31.745339: I tensorflow_serving/model_servers/server.cc:86] Building single TensorFlow model file config:  model_name: photo2sketch model_base_path: /models/photo2sketch
2020-06-17 12:57:31.745448: I tensorflow_serving/model_servers/server_core.cc:464] Adding/updating models.
2020-06-17 12:57:31.745459: I tensorflow_serving/model_servers/server_core.cc:575]  (Re-)adding model: photo2sketch
2020-06-17 12:57:31.846162: I tensorflow_serving/core/basic_manager.cc:739] Successfully reserved resources to load servable {name: photo2sketch version: 1}
2020-06-17 12:57:31.846213: I tensorflow_serving/core/loader_harness.cc:66] Approving load for servable version {name: photo2sketch version: 1}
2020-06-17 12:57:31.846233: I tensorflow_serving/core/loader_harness.cc:74] Loading servable version {name: photo2sketch version: 1}
2020-06-17 12:57:31.846282: I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/saved_model/reader.cc:31] Reading SavedModel from: /models/photo2sketch/1
2020-06-17 12:57:31.874158: I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/saved_model/reader.cc:54] Reading meta graph with tags { serve }
2020-06-17 12:57:31.874182: I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.cc:295] Reading SavedModel debug info (if present) from: /models/photo2sketch/1
2020-06-17 12:57:31.874315: I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:143] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
2020-06-17 12:57:31.952982: I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.cc:234] Restoring SavedModel bundle.
2020-06-17 12:57:32.172641: I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.cc:183] Running initialization op on SavedModel bundle at path: /models/photo2sketch/1
2020-06-17 12:57:32.248514: I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.cc:364] SavedModel load for tags { serve }; Status: success: OK. Took 402236 microseconds.
2020-06-17 12:57:32.256576: I tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow/saved_model_warmup.cc:105] No warmup data file found at /models/photo2sketch/1/assets.extra/tf_serving_warmup_requests
2020-06-17 12:57:32.265064: I tensorflow_serving/core/loader_harness.cc:87] Successfully loaded servable version {name: photo2sketch version: 1}
2020-06-17 12:57:32.267113: I tensorflow_serving/model_servers/server.cc:355] Running gRPC ModelServer at 0.0.0.0:8500 ...
[warn] getaddrinfo: address family for nodename not supported
2020-06-17 12:57:32.269289: I tensorflow_serving/model_servers/server.cc:375] Exporting HTTP/REST API at:localhost:8501 ...
[evhttp_server.cc : 238] NET_LOG: Entering the event loop ...
```

When I predict by REST request, it return NaN with correct shape:

```
[[[[nan nan nan]
   [nan nan nan]
   [nan nan nan]
   ...
   [nan nan nan]
   [nan nan nan]
   [nan nan nan]]
```

Anybody knows why? How can I debug it? Thanks very much!

Comment: I try serve another model(LSTM to classify). It works well. 
Emm..
So maybe generator model has bug?

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same problem with my Pix2Pix generator. The problem was with the training parameter. As explained here [What does `training=True` mean when calling a TensorFlow Keras model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57320371/what-does-training-true-mean-when-calling-a-tensorflow-keras-model) this parameter affects the results of the network. One possible solution is to remove all dropouts (and other affected parts) prior to saving the network. This solution did not work for me (probably missed something). So instead as a temporary workaround, I added 2 signatures to the model

```
@tf.function(input_signature=[tf.TensorSpec([None, 256,256,3], dtype=tf.float32)])
def model_predict1(input_batch):
  return {'outputs': generator(input_batch, training=True)}

@tf.function(input_signature=[tf.TensorSpec([None, 256,256,3], dtype=tf.float32)])
def model_predict2(input_batch):
  return {'outputs': generator(input_batch, training=False)}
...
generator.save(base_path + "kerassave",signatures={'predict1': model_predict1, 'predict2': model_predict2})
```

predict2 still always returned nans. predict1 worked, however.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I will try it!

Comment: How does `training=True` affect the model predicitons? As I understand it, during training, dropouts would randonmly remove nodes/branches but not during prediction. 
Does this mean, during inference, setting `training=True` we potentially might have different results when passing the same image for prediction? Cheers!