# Why is there an Invalid Argument exception while Training a EfficientNet CNN on a seemingly random Epoch?

Tags: keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, invalid-argument, efficientnet

I'm trying to train different EfficientNet models to be able to classify Music Genres. First i transform the audios i have into Mel-Spectrograms and train a model with these. It is a multi-label classification, i use a sigmoid layer as a last prediction layer and binary crossentropy as a loss function. I used different metrics like binary accuracy and Recall, but mostly binary accuracy. I use Transfer learning to first transfer an existing EfficientNetB1 (or also EfficientNetB3) model onto the new dataset of mine, which consists of ~67k pictures (spectrograms) with 16 genres/classes, a label consists of 1 to 4 classes (one-hot-encoded). After that the model is saved an loaded again for fine tuning, most layers are unfrozen (besides the BatchNormalization layers). Learning rate for transfering the model is 0.01 and for fine tuning it is 0.001. In recent versions i used class weights for training to act on the imbalance in my dataset.

So, after transfering the model, while fine tuning, the training eventually (not on all runs though) just stops because of following exception (i also include the whole training log):

```
Python Tensorflow Version (nightly version) - 2.4.0-dev20200704
CLASSES: {32, 1, 66, 41, 42, 10, 12, 76, 107, 17, 18, 1235, 21, 25, 250, 27}
TRAINING IMAGES: 59142
VALIDATION IMAGES: 7805
Total number of Training samples: 
TRAIN: 59136
VAL: 7800
Steps per epoch: 7392
Validation Steps: 975
2021-02-23 14:15:07.741865: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1
2021-02-23 14:15:07.771234: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1716] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:86:00.0 name: Tesla K80 computeCapability: 3.7
coreClock: 0.8235GHz coreCount: 13 deviceMemorySize: 11.17GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 223.96GiB/s
2021-02-23 14:15:07.771295: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
2021-02-23 14:15:07.806741: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10
2021-02-23 14:15:07.808235: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10
2021-02-23 14:15:07.808550: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10
2021-02-23 14:15:07.810184: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10
2021-02-23 14:15:07.810985: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10
2021-02-23 14:15:07.829478: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2021-02-23 14:15:07.832361: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1858] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2021-02-23 14:15:07.832759: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN)to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2021-02-23 14:15:07.866705: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:104] CPU Frequency: 3092840000 Hz
2021-02-23 14:15:07.867161: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x60a5b70 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2021-02-23 14:15:07.867204: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
2021-02-23 14:15:07.953336: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x609d8b0 initialized for platform CUDA (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2021-02-23 14:15:07.953391: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Tesla K80, Compute Capability 3.7
2021-02-23 14:15:07.955334: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1716] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:86:00.0 name: Tesla K80 computeCapability: 3.7
coreClock: 0.8235GHz coreCount: 13 deviceMemorySize: 11.17GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 223.96GiB/s
2021-02-23 14:15:07.955389: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
2021-02-23 14:15:07.955456: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10
2021-02-23 14:15:07.955499: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10
2021-02-23 14:15:07.955542: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10
2021-02-23 14:15:07.955584: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10
2021-02-23 14:15:07.955625: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10
2021-02-23 14:15:07.955667: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2021-02-23 14:15:07.959120: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1858] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2021-02-23 14:15:07.959174: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
2021-02-23 14:15:08.467663: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1257] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2021-02-23 14:15:08.467725: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1263]      0 
2021-02-23 14:15:08.467737: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1276] 0:   N 
2021-02-23 14:15:08.470827: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1402] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 10617 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: Tesla K80, pci bus id: 0000:86:00.0, compute capability: 3.7)
2021-02-23 14:15:14.300401: I tensorflow/core/profiler/lib/profiler_session.cc:164] Profiler session started.
2021-02-23 14:15:14.300477: I tensorflow/core/profiler/internal/gpu/cupti_tracer.cc:1391] Profiler found 1 GPUs
2021-02-23 14:15:14.300872: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:59] Could not load dynamic library 'libcupti.so.10.1'; dlerror: libcupti.so.10.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: ~/.local/lib:/usr/local/cuda-10.1/lib64:/usr/local/nvidia/lib:/usr/local/nvidia/lib64
2021-02-23 14:15:14.300989: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:59] Could not load dynamic library 'libcupti.so'; dlerror: libcupti.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: ~/.local/lib:/usr/local/cuda-10.1/lib64:/usr/local/nvidia/lib:/usr/local/nvidia/lib64
2021-02-23 14:15:14.301009: E tensorflow/core/profiler/internal/gpu/cupti_tracer.cc:1441] function cupti_interface_->Subscribe( &subscriber_, (CUpti_CallbackFunc)ApiCallback, this)failed with error CUPTI could not be loaded or symbol could not be found.
START OF TRAINING NOW!
Epoch 1/10
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/user06/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/multi_device_iterator_ops.py:601: get_next_as_optional (from tensorflow.python.data.ops.iterator_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.data.Iterator.get_next_as_optional()` instead.
2021-02-23 14:15:24.859460: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10
2021-02-23 14:15:25.675793: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
7392/7392 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.3681 - binary_accuracy: 0.8819 - recall: 0.0837   
Epoch 00001: val_loss improved from inf to 0.32435, saving model to /home/user06/GenreClassification/GenreClassification/data/checkpoints/EfficientNetB1_transfer_01_old-test4_01_0.32.hdf5
7392/7392 [==============================] - 2204s 298ms/step - loss: 0.3681 - binary_accuracy: 0.8819 - recall: 0.0837 - val_loss: 0.3244 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8756 - val_recall: 0.1175
Epoch 2/10
7392/7392 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.3574 - binary_accuracy: 0.8835 - recall: 0.0803   
Epoch 00002: val_loss did not improve from 0.32435
7392/7392 [==============================] - 1776s 240ms/step - loss: 0.3574 - binary_accuracy: 0.8835 - recall: 0.0803 - val_loss: 0.3474 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8754 - val_recall: 0.0971
Epoch 3/10
7392/7392 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.3565 - binary_accuracy: 0.8840 - recall: 0.0788   
Epoch 00003: val_loss did not improve from 0.32435
7392/7392 [==============================] - 1582s 214ms/step - loss: 0.3565 - binary_accuracy: 0.8840 - recall: 0.0788 - val_loss: 0.3469 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8683 - val_recall: 0.1250
Epoch 4/10
7392/7392 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.3564 - binary_accuracy: 0.8840 - recall: 0.0790     
Epoch 00004: val_loss did not improve from 0.32435
7392/7392 [==============================] - 1564s 212ms/step - loss: 0.3564 - binary_accuracy: 0.8840 - recall: 0.0790 - val_loss: 0.3337 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8765 - val_recall: 0.1108
Epoch 5/10
7392/7392 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.3569 - binary_accuracy: 0.8836 - recall: 0.0781   
Epoch 00005: val_loss did not improve from 0.32435
7392/7392 [==============================] - 1564s 212ms/step - loss: 0.3569 - binary_accuracy: 0.8836 - recall: 0.0781 - val_loss: 0.3472 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8735 - val_recall: 0.0962
Epoch 6/10
7392/7392 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.3567 - binary_accuracy: 0.8837 - recall: 0.0801     
Epoch 00006: val_loss did not improve from 0.32435
7392/7392 [==============================] - 1568s 212ms/step - loss: 0.3567 - binary_accuracy: 0.8837 - recall: 0.0801 - val_loss: 0.3266 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8783 - val_recall: 0.1191
Epoch 7/10
7392/7392 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.3565 - binary_accuracy: 0.8842 - recall: 0.0788   
Epoch 00007: val_loss did not improve from 0.32435
7392/7392 [==============================] - 1568s 212ms/step - loss: 0.3565 - binary_accuracy: 0.8842 - recall: 0.0788 - val_loss: 0.3410 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8756 - val_recall: 0.1026
Epoch 8/10
7392/7392 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.3567 - binary_accuracy: 0.8841 - recall: 0.0788    
Epoch 00008: val_loss did not improve from 0.32435
7392/7392 [==============================] - 1683s 228ms/step - loss: 0.3567 - binary_accuracy: 0.8841 - recall: 0.0788 - val_loss: 0.3749 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8727 - val_recall: 0.0643
Epoch 9/10
7392/7392 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.3575 - binary_accuracy: 0.8839 - recall: 0.0780   
Epoch 00009: val_loss did not improve from 0.32435
7392/7392 [==============================] - 1634s 221ms/step - loss: 0.3575 - binary_accuracy: 0.8839 - recall: 0.0780 - val_loss: 0.3842 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8561 - val_recall: 0.1199
Epoch 10/10
7392/7392 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.3569 - binary_accuracy: 0.8840 - recall: 0.0776   
Epoch 00010: val_loss did not improve from 0.32435
7392/7392 [==============================] - 1585s 214ms/step - loss: 0.3569 - binary_accuracy: 0.8840 - recall: 0.0776 - val_loss: 0.3378 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8808 - val_recall: 0.1001
2021-02-23 18:54:20.781432: I tensorflow/core/profiler/lib/profiler_session.cc:164] Profiler session started.
2021-02-23 18:54:20.781518: E tensorflow/core/profiler/internal/gpu/cupti_tracer.cc:1441] function cupti_interface_->Subscribe( &subscriber_, (CUpti_CallbackFunc)ApiCallback, this)failed with error CUPTI could not be loaded or symbol could not be found.
START OF TRAINING NOW!
Epoch 1/10
7392/7392 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.3620 - binary_accuracy: 0.8917 - recall_1: 9.7708e-05   
Epoch 00001: val_loss improved from inf to 0.36043, saving model to /home/user06/GenreClassification/GenreClassification/data/checkpoints/EfficientNetB1_transfer_01_old-test4_tuned_01_0.36.hdf5
7392/7392 [==============================] - 3149s 426ms/step - loss: 0.3620 - binary_accuracy: 0.8917 - recall_1: 9.7708e-05 - val_loss: 0.3604 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8823 - val_recall_1: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 2/10
7392/7392 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.3578 - binary_accuracy: 0.8918 - recall_1: 0.0000e+00Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "evaluate.py", line 87, in <module>
    r = evaluate(sys.argv[1])
IndexError: list index out of range

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "evaluate.py", line 89, in <module>
    r = evaluate()
  File "evaluate.py", line 73, in evaluate
    model_name, model = train.train_model(model, TRAIN_GEN, VAL_GEN, VAL_STEPS, strategy, CLASS_WEIGHTS, t_step=2)
  File "/home/user06/GenreClassification/GenreClassification/src/process/train.py", line 205, in train_model
    class_weight=class_weights)
  File "/home/user06/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 108, in _method_wrapper
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user06/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1137, in fit
    return_dict=True)
  File "/home/user06/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 108, in _method_wrapper
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user06/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1383, in evaluate
    tmp_logs = test_function(iterator)
  File "/home/user06/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 780, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "/home/user06/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 814, in _call
    results = self._stateful_fn(*args, **kwds)
  File "/home/user06/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 2844, in __call__
    return graph_function._filtered_call(args, kwargs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "/home/user06/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 1847, in _filtered_call
    cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager)
  File "/home/user06/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 1923, in _call_flat
    ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager))
  File "/home/user06/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 550, in call
    ctx=ctx)
  File "/home/user06/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py", line 60, in quick_execute
    inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Invalid argument:  assertion failed: [predictions must be >= 0] [Condition x >= y did not hold element-wise:] [x (EffNetB1/top_predictions_custom/Sigmoid:0) = ] [[nan nan nan...]...] [y (Cast_8/x:0) = ] [0]
     [[{{node assert_greater_equal/Assert/AssertGuard/else/_21/assert_greater_equal/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert}}]]
     [[div_no_nan_2/ReadVariableOp/_56]]
  (1) Invalid argument:  assertion failed: [predictions must be >= 0] [Condition x >= y did not hold element-wise:] [x (EffNetB1/top_predictions_custom/Sigmoid:0) = ] [[nan nan nan...]...] [y (Cast_8/x:0) = ] [0]
     [[{{node assert_greater_equal/Assert/AssertGuard/else/_21/assert_greater_equal/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert}}]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored. [Op:__inference_test_function_327987]

Function call stack:
test_function -> test_function

terminate called without an active exception
Aborted (core dumped)
```

This exception seems to be thrown randomly, because sometimes the training just works fine and other times it does not, that is why this is a massive problem for me. I'm dealing with this now since more than 1 week and can't seem to find a solution. I tried to alter the batch size, i use 8 normally, becuase the memory is not enough for more pictures in one batch on most GPUs that i use. I tried to not use class wights, still the model fails sometimes. I tried to leave out certain metrics and just use the accuracy, still the training fails at some point.

Any help or direction is very much appreciated. For further information please tell me, this is my second question on stack overflow, i'm fairly new to this.

I noticed, that i can also include the code for my model creation and Training, So first the model creation (build_efficientNetB3_model):

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications.efficientnet import EfficientNetB3, EfficientNetB1, EfficientNetB0
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model, Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, GlobalAveragePooling2D, Input, concatenate, Conv2D, BatchNormalization, \
    Activation, MaxPool2D, Flatten, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD, RMSprop, Adam
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import BinaryAccuracy, FalseNegatives, FalsePositives, Recall, Precision
import config as conf

def create_eff(TRANSFER: conf.Transfer):
    input_tensor = Input(shape=(conf.IM_SIZE[0], conf.IM_SIZE[1], conf.IM_DIM), name='input_specs')

    if conf.EFFICIENT_VERSION is conf.EfficientNet.B0:
        # rescaling of image size from 300x300 to 224x224 is done in one of the first layers of B0
        base_model = EfficientNetB0(include_top=False, input_tensor=input_tensor, weights='imagenet')
    elif conf.EFFICIENT_VERSION is conf.EfficientNet.B1:
        # rescaling of image size from 300x300 to 240x240 is done in one of the first layers of B1
        base_model = EfficientNetB1(include_top=False, input_tensor=input_tensor, weights='imagenet')
    elif conf.EFFICIENT_VERSION is conf.EfficientNet.B3:
        base_model = EfficientNetB3(include_top=False, input_tensor=input_tensor, weights='imagenet')

    # Freeze the pretrained weights here for Transfer Learning, all layers besides the newly added ones.
    if TRANSFER.value:
        base_model.trainable = False

    # Rebuild top
    x = GlobalAveragePooling2D(name="top_avg_pool_custom")(base_model.output)
    x = BatchNormalization(name="top_batch_normalization_custom")(x)
    x = Dropout(0.2, name="top_dropout_custom")(x)

    model = Model(base_model.input, x)

    print(f'Is the model trainable? Default is trainable, not trainable in case all layers are set so not trainable. '
          f'[{model.trainable}]')

    return model


def build_efficientNetB3_model(classes: set, TRANSFER: conf.Transfer):
    conf.CLASSES = classes

    eff_model = create_eff(TRANSFER)

    # A logistic layer -- with x classes
    predictions = Dense(len(conf.CLASSES), activation='sigmoid', name='top_predictions_custom')(eff_model.output)
    model = Model(inputs=eff_model.input, outputs=predictions, name=f"EffNet{conf.EFFICIENT_VERSION.value}")

    for i, layer in enumerate(model.layers):
        print(i, layer.name, layer.trainable)

    lr = 1e-3
    if TRANSFER.value:
        lr = 1e-2
    optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=lr)

    model.compile(
        optimizer=optimizer, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=[BinaryAccuracy(), Recall()]  # Specificity(), Precision()
    ) 

    return model


def unfreeze_model(model):
    # We unfreeze the top layers while leaving BatchNorm layers frozen
    for layer in model.layers:
        if not isinstance(layer, BatchNormalization):
            layer.trainable = True

    # Once the model has converged to new data, the learning rate for re-training on unfrozen model should be low
    optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=1e-3)
    model.compile(
        optimizer=optimizer, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=[BinaryAccuracy(), Recall()]  # Specificity(), Precision()
    )
```

Now the Training (Files are evaluate.py and train.py):

evaluate.py

```
def evaluate(argv=None):
    # Evaluate the command line argument, should for now be YES or NO to activate Transfer Learning
    try:
        args = getopt.getopt(argv, "")
        print(args)
    except getopt.GetoptError:
        print('args exception')

    # default for Transfer Learning is YES, argument needs to be set to not use Transfer Learning
    TRANSFER = Transfer['YES']
    if args[1] is not None:
        TRANSFER = Transfer[args[1]]

    subtrack_dict = uio.load_pickle(conf.SUB_PARSED_TRACKS_V3)
    TRACKS = subtrack_dict['parsed_tracks'] 
    conf.CURRENT_SET = conf.SET.SUB_LARGE_V3

    # Parse Dataset
    conf.CLASSES, TRAIN, VAL = train.parseTrainSet(tracks=TRACKS)
    # Prepare generators for training
    TRAIN_GEN, VAL_GEN, VAL_STEPS = train.prepare_generators(TRAIN, VAL)

    CLASS_WEIGHTS = cws.calculate_class_weights(tracks=TRACKS)

    strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()

    # Get the EfficientNetB3 model
    with strategy.scope():
        MODEL = k_net.build_efficientNetB3_model(conf.CLASSES, TRANSFER)
    if not TRANSFER.value:  # Use no transfer learning
        # Train and return trained net
        model_name, model = train.train_model(MODEL, TRAIN_GEN, VAL_GEN, VAL_STEPS, strategy, CLASS_WEIGHTS)
        del model
    else:
        #  1. Training mittels Transfer Lerning, nur die top Schichten mit Anzahl EPOCHS_TRANSFER an epochen. (t_step=1)
        #  2. Anpassen des Modells mittels einer Funktion wie "unfreeze()", da sollte auch die Anpassung der
        #  Lernrate enthalten sein.
        #  3. Fine-Tuning des angepassten Modells mit Anzahl EPOCHS an Epochen und neuen checkpoints. (t_step=2)
        model_name, model = train.train_model(MODEL, TRAIN_GEN, VAL_GEN, VAL_STEPS, strategy, CLASS_WEIGHTS, t_step=1)
        with strategy.scope():
            k_net.unfreeze_model(model)
        model_name, model = train.train_model(model, TRAIN_GEN, VAL_GEN, VAL_STEPS, strategy, CLASS_WEIGHTS, t_step=2)
```

train.py

```
def train_model(MODEL, training_generator, validation_generator, validation_steps, strategy, class_weights, t_step=-1):
    logdir = os.path.join(conf.TENSORBOARD_LOGS_PATH,
                          conf.RUN_NAME + '_' + datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S"))

    with strategy.scope():
        if t_step is 2:
            checkdir = os.path.join(conf.CHECKPOINTS_PATH, conf.RUN_NAME + "_tuned"
                                    + "_{epoch:02d}_{val_loss:.2f}.hdf5")
        else:
            checkdir = os.path.join(conf.CHECKPOINTS_PATH, conf.RUN_NAME + "_{epoch:02d}_{val_loss:.2f}.hdf5")
        checkpoint = callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(checkdir, monitor='val_loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=True,
                                               save_weights_only=True, mode='auto', save_freq='epoch')

    if t_step is 1:
        epochs = conf.EPOCHS_TRANSFER
    else:
        epochs = conf.EPOCHS

    class_weights = class_weights if conf.USE_CLASS_WEIGHTS else None

    print('START OF TRAINING NOW!')
    hist = MODEL.fit(x=training_generator, epochs=epochs, verbose=1, callbacks=[checkpoint],
                     validation_data=validation_generator, validation_steps=validation_steps,
                     class_weight=class_weights)

    kio.saveModel(MODEL, hist, conf.CLASSES)  # save on existing model (correct behaviour)

    return conf.RUN_NAME, MODEL
```

Comment: The error message shows `nan` values appearing, which hints at numerical issues. This is most likely either due to problems with your data (check it for nans or very large values) or instabilities in the model. For the latter you could try reducing the learning rate or using gradient clipping.

Comment: @xdurch0 thank you for your answer. I will look into my data to see if there are any nans or any other suspicious values. I will also try using gradient clipping.

Comment: So for now the training works well and i just reduced the learning rate while fine tuning from **0.001** to **0.0001** (if anybody stumbles upon this question and has a similar problem).

Comment: Maybe this is related to this issue: https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/issues/1670.

There also is a similar question here on SO where one suggested answer was to set the 'training' parameter of the network to True even when only predicting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62440808/tensorflow-serving-returning-nan-when-predict/62483768#62483768