# Different loss values computed by train_on_batch and evaluate

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

Evaluation before batch training, training on batch and post training returns different loss values.

```
pre_train_loss = model.evaluate(batch_x, batch_y, verbose=0)
train_loss = model.train_on_batch(batch_x, batch_y)
post_train_loss = model.evaluate(batch_x, batch_y, verbose=0)


Pre batch train loss  : 2.3195652961730957
train_on_batch loss   : 2.3300909996032715
Post batch train loss : 2.2722578048706055
```

I assumed `train_on_batch` returns loss computed **before** parameters update (before backpropagation). But `pre_train_loss` and `train_loss` are not **exacly** the same. Moreover all loss values are different.

Is my assumption of `train_on_batch` right? If so, why all loss values are different?

[Colab example](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1OdZlQ1pbU5rK0AzwhQKHSXFikGZCazYm?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me give you a detailed explanation of what is going on.

Calling `model.evaluate` (or `model.test_on_batch`) will invoke the `model.make_test_function` which will invoke the `model.test_step` and this function does following:

```
y_pred = self(x, training=False)
# Updates stateful loss metrics.
self.compiled_loss(
    y, y_pred, sample_weight, regularization_losses=self.losses)
```

Calling `model.train_on_batch` will invoke the `model.make_train_function` which will invoke the `model.train_step` and this function does following:

```
with backprop.GradientTape() as tape:
  y_pred = self(x, training=True)
  loss = self.compiled_loss(
      y, y_pred, sample_weight, regularization_losses=self.losses)
```

As you can see from above source code, the only difference between `model.test_step` and `model.train_step` when compute the loss is whether `training=True` when forward pass data to model.

Because some neural network layers behave differently during training and inference (e.g Dropout and BatchNormalization layers), so we have `training` argument for let those layer know which of the two "paths" it should take, e.g:

- During training, dropout will randomly drop out units and correspondingly scale up activations of the remaining units.
- During inference, it does nothing (since you usually don't want the randomness of dropping out units here).

Since you have dropout layer in your model, so the loss increase in training mode is expected.

If you remove the line `layers.Dropout(0.5),` when define the model you will see the loss is nearly identical (i.e with little floating point precision mismatch), e.g outputs of three epoch:

```
Epoch: 1
Pre batch train loss  : 1.6852061748504639
train_on_batch loss   : 1.6852061748504639
Post batch train loss : 1.6012675762176514

Pre batch train loss  : 1.7325702905654907
train_on_batch loss   : 1.7325704097747803
Post batch train loss : 1.6512296199798584

Epoch: 2
Pre batch train loss  : 1.5149778127670288
train_on_batch loss   : 1.5149779319763184
Post batch train loss : 1.4209072589874268

Pre batch train loss  : 1.567994475364685
train_on_batch loss   : 1.5679945945739746
Post batch train loss : 1.4767804145812988

Epoch: 3
Pre batch train loss  : 1.3269715309143066
train_on_batch loss   : 1.3269715309143066
Post batch train loss : 1.2274967432022095

Pre batch train loss  : 1.3868262767791748
train_on_batch loss   : 1.3868262767791748
Post batch train loss : 1.2916004657745361
```

**Reference:**

[Documents and source code link of `tf.keras.Model`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model)

[What does `training=True` mean when calling a TensorFlow Keras model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57320371/what-does-training-true-mean-when-calling-a-tensorflow-keras-model)